# Bundle SciLab binaries with java application

Tags: java, scilab

I am using javasci in my java application to call SciLab scripts. I'd like to include needed binaries from SciLab with my application. So I can avoid SciLab installation for the application to run.

Did someone already tried this? Any tips on which files/dlls to take? And how to configure them so they are accessible to javasci?